# Nginx Rails Deflate JS file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, compression, gzip

I have an app that I'd like to optimize.  After adding the following gzip config to Nginx I still get errors that the following files are not compressed and could save 400k in load.

```
Config:
# output compression saves bandwidth
  gzip  on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/rdf+xml;

  # make sure gzip does not lose large gzipped js or css files
  # see http://blog.leetsoft.com/2007/7/25/nginx-gzip-ssl
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;

  # Disable gzip for certain browsers.
  gzip_disable “MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)”;

Files:
Compressing the following resources with gzip could reduce their transfer size by 445.6KiB (77% reduction).
Compressing https://cad.hcem.com/.../application-c58641bce5c2c94f380075bb5... could save 272.1KiB (73% reduction).
Compressing https://cad.hcem.com/.../application-99c35c4a0df5a19bfd5ed6938... could save 173.5KiB (84% reduction).
```

In my config I seem to have javascript already turned on for compression.  Am I missing something that won't compress these files out of the pipeline?

Comment: what is the the Content-Type http header of the files that aren't being compressed?

Comment: Looks like my cut/paste was cutoff.  These are JS files, the main application.js files that runs through the Asset pipeline.

Comment: which means they _should_ be getting served with a Content-Type matching your gzip_types. Did you validate that's indeed the case? I haven't spotted anyhting wrong in your posted config, it oughta work. If the problem is the Content-Type it's getting served with, next place to look is your /etc/nginx/mime.types

Answer (score 0):

Put a `#` in front of the long `gzip_types` line

and add

```
gzip_types
    # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
    text/css 
    text/javascript
    text/xml
    text/plain
    text/x-component
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/rss+xml
    font/truetype
    font/opentype
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    image/svg+xml;
```